# Nginx: Wordpress: Blank Page

Tags: linux, nginx, php-fpm, wordpress, linuxmint

When I try to access my webserver, I get a blank page. It is set up to work with wordpress, but it doesn't.

This is my wordpress.conf (located in conf.d):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  #listen 443 default ssl;

  server_name snapecraft.ddns.net;
  root /var/www/html;

  #ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.crt;
  #ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.key;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

  index index.php index.phtml index.html;

  error_page   500 502 503 504 404  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }


  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

  }
}
```

When I do `curl -I snapecraft.ddns.net` this is the result:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.15.5
Date: Fri, 26 Oct 2018 16:41:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://snapecraft.ddns.net/
```

This is my nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

This is the php.ini file:
https://pastebin.com/P6UccG70

**Of course I reloaded nginx and PHP**

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress can be set to force https, but you have commented those lines out on your `wordpress.conf`. Your server is not answering  on HTTPS, but does a redirection to it.

You have two options:

1. Make `http://snapecraft.ddns.net/` (without TLS) the canonical address for your site.
2. Set up the TLS enabled `https://snapecraft.ddns.net/`.

This day and age you should choose option 2.